# How to display graduated symbol in the legend in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, printing

This is the problem: why the graduated symbol is not reported at all in the legend of the print composer? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? Here below an image that shows the problem:

[image]

Comment: Go into layer style, advanced - and make sure size scale field is checked on 'no field'. This did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specified your [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) version.

But, in `QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour`, maybe it isn't checked `Auto Update`.

[image]

Or, if it is checked, what happens when you add the graduated symbol layer, pressing the **`+`** button?

Comment: hi sorry for not mentioning the version of QGIS...is 2.0. the single symbol and categorised type of classification work perfectly, the graduated colour no. I think is a bug, unfortunately. No changes if i update the files or if i click on the green plus bottom.